# If statement in for loop referencing incremented variable

Tags: google-apps-script

as quite an novice when it comes to coding, I ran into this problem with my code:
I use Google App Script [Edit: Corrected Google App Engine to Google App Script] to go through a list of timestamps and filter for stamps that equal the current month. Therefor I load the spreadsheet, the according sheet and get the data from all the rows as an object.

In the next step I go though all the elements of the object and check whether they contain the current date.

```
    /* Initial data */  

  var email = "name@domain.com";  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1bN7PTOa6PwryVvcGxzDxuNVkeZMRwYKAGFnQvxJ_0nU");
  var tasklist = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getDataRange(); 
  var tasks = tasklist.getValues();
  var tasksnum = tasklist.getNumRows();

  Logger.log(tasks[7][2]); //Console returns "01.12.2014"
  Logger.log(tasks[7][2].indexOf(month)); //Console returns "12.2014"

/* Filter tasks by month */  

  for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {  
    if (tasks[i][2].indexOf(month) >= 0) {
      Logger.log(tasks[i]);
    }
    else {
      return;
    }
  }
```

What drives me crazy is the following: As stated above, the for loop doesn't work. But if I alter it like this

```
if (tasks[7][2].indexOf(month) >= o) {
```

it works like a charm. And that's what I don't get. i should be incremented til 9 so should be seven at some point. At least then, the condition should be true and the loop should return a log.

What am I missing?

Thank you all in advance.

ps: If I am just following the wrong path of how to implement the function, please let me know.
ps2: I think my question's title is a bit cryptic. If you have a better one in mind, I'd love to change it.

Comment: By the way, you aren't using the Google App Engine here, or at least not in a way that's relevant to your question. Google Apps Script runs on Google Drive, Google App Engine is an entirely separate product that runs applications developed in Python, Java, PHP or GO, not Google Apps Script.   The names are a bit confusing. If you are searching for help on Apps Script, don't use the term Google App Engine or you will get misleading results.

Comment: Thank you for that note. I changed my post to clear it up. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your original code doesn't work is due to the return statement in your else block. Return exits the function immediately, so your loop never gets past the first "false" of your IF.

remove the "return" (or the else block entirely) and your code should work.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick indeed. I am still on a very basic level, but it's great that one can even find help for trivial errors.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Often in programming we make assumptions that lead us in the wrong direction, in this case you were assuming the loop was running all 9 times, when in fact it was not.  My number one tip for anyone confused by the behaviour of their code is "Check Your Assumptions!".  In this case, if you had put a Logger.log(i); immediately after the for loop, you would have seen it wasn't getting up to 7, and that might have steered you towards the return statement.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's supposed to be in the `month` variable but I suggested building a string to match your date format and doing string comparisons instead of the indexOf() strategy you're trying. This code is tested and does just that:

```
function test() {
  /* Initial data */  

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("");
  var tasklist = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getDataRange(); 
  var tasks = tasklist.getValues();
  var tasksnum = tasklist.getNumRows();

  /* Filter tasks by month */  
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(
    new Date(), 
    spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 
    "dd.MM.yyyy"
  );

  for(var i=1; i<9; i++){  
    if (tasks[i][2] == today){
      Logger.log(tasks[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this looks indeed like a far more elegant solution. Thanks a lot. :-)

But my problem is, that all the time stamps in the table are different (for example: 02.12.2014 17:07:32; 02.12.2014 17:07:32; 02.12.2014 17:07:32). I would like to filter them for their common feature, which is month and year (12.2014). Or is it possible to re-format the plain text string from the table to meet the format of MM.YYYY?

Comment: This can be done with a regular expression. I can help show you how to use one if you create a new question.